# After upgrade windows7 -> windows10 windows cannot see valid HDD

Tags: windows-10

I'm windows newbie, but I had to reinstall the system for someone. After the installation windows 10 cannot see the older harddrive.

precondition: working system with windows 7.

reinstall: during reinstall I kept connected only SSD for main system, and unplugged eSATA cable of data HDD. This is my habbit after one instance, when Windows dropped all partition tables on all other drives during installation(while I'm super positive that I did not asked for that). It's not pleasant having to fix that. After full installation, I powered off, plugged data cable back in, but dics isn't detected. No HW change, no cabling change, no bios change. Just one plug-out and plug-in of 1 cable.

testing done: the disc is fine. NTFS FS is fine. I can plug it to linux machine and it works. I can put it into external box, and connect it to the problematic machine and it can see and read the drive! If I put it back to problematic machine, try to use several power supply cables, several different eSATA cables, different sata connectors, the result is still the same. HDD is whirring, BIOS can see the drive, "windows partition table program" (the default one which is shipped with windows, I don't know the correct name, and I don't have US locale windows version) does not see it. Bios has 2 modes for this drive, with esata enabled and disabled. I tried both, but again, with former setting windows 7 worked.

I did not yet test power from "faulty" pc and data through external box, but I think this has very litle chance of showing anything different. If drive is spinning and bios can detect it, I doubt it can be caused by insufficient power from power unit. I will debug HW by booting linux on this machine, and post a results here, but otherwise ...

I'm running out of ideas.

What can be wrong, that windows 10 cannot see valid HDD, with OK cabling and not corrupted partition? Is there some "please work" switch or anything I did not yet test?

EDIT: I did check the "device manager" (again, not sure about correct naming due to non-us locale). No disks were marked as errorneous OR show any error what so ever. !!!HOWEVER!!! I was able to fix the issue here. I'll post answer here.

**Kind request to answer reviewers voting for closing**: IT is sometimes crazy world (wait for the answer to this question), and even if you find something trivial, it need not mean, that it is trivial and unhelpful to everyone. I don't think this question is example of lack of effort, insufficient info etc. Please be less trigger-eager to kill someones valid question. Thanks. **At least** state why are you voting like that.

Comment: do a online search for information regarding a conflict between your ssd model number and your hdd model number or a more generalized search for conflict between ssd and hdd. Next time, in addition to un-plugging the hdd data cable un-plug the power cable also.  The chance that it will solve your problem is so remote that I am not going to suggest you un-plug both the hdd data and power cable and re-install windows.

Comment: what? what could went wrong during that installation in your opinion? How do you think windows can do sth with HDD connected only to powersource??

Comment: This could be a SATA driver issue. One thing you didn't mention is going into device manager and seeing if there is an error/warning relating to a SATA interface?

Comment: Have you considered putting Microsoft's Windows in a Virtual-box in Gnu/Linux?

Comment: @davidgo will check and update in 2h (dont have pc access now).

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor no, pc owner does not have any linux skills or desire in this area. Using plain windows must be sufficient. And frankly, using hdd with windows OS is definitely supported.

Comment: @MartinMucha It was just an idea. My dad had no computing skills. He was struggling with MS-Windows. I put Debian on his machine, he found it much easier. Mainly because it is self-consistent, and generally easier to use.

Comment: In the past I had a HDD that was not recognised by MS-Windows. The formatting tool would not even recognise it. We but it into a Unix machine and cleared the first few sectors to zeros. Then moved it back, the MS-Windows formatted was then happy to set it up, and we could use it.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor thx for hint. It depends on personality. For people, who aren't afraid of change and do not insist on everything to be just like in windows, I'd definitely suggest cinnamon env on debian, sure. But this is not the case of this <pc owner>. He want's windows and no changes in his work style.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor never heard of such issue, even with some more exotic file-systems I was always at least possible to see unsupported drive. But yes, I trust you -- see my answer ;) what actually helped me. I didn't have possibility to linux format, because of data was on it, and I wasn't convinced that this could help. Now I know, that unplugging during installation is really important safety feature, and anything can happen in windows :D

Comment: Thanks to every one reading my question and trying to help me! I really appreciate your time and effort!

Comment: @MartinMucha it was a long long time ago (Pre XP).

Comment: What are the makes and models of the drives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found out how to fix this. I did not even got to verifying HW using live-usb linux. I opened "device manager" to check HDD drivers and it's state. There we 3. One for usb storage device, and 2 unidentifiable, having bizarre names. I double click first one, and saw tabs like "general/privileges/volumes/driver/details/events" (again, I'm translating from local locale to us locale). If you're familiar with windows, you will find correct tabs using these names. Driver did not show any issue, but I went into tab named "volumes".

In this tab, there are "group boxes": information about drive and information about volumes on that drive. Both are empty. But there is Load button on the left. So I clicked it. I takes a while, and after that in upper groupbox shows information about HDD, that it's online, it's total and free capacity, etc. In lower groupbox there is again information about size and which letter is assigned to this volume.

Suriprisingly the very first drive I tried showed assigned letter D, which is the one which wasn't working ANYWHERE in system, including the volume manager, where you can see all partitions and format them. And guess what! Now the drive is available everywhere in the system!!! What the actual ... hell! The windows does actually have "please work" button you can click and made not detected missing drive as 100% working. Insanely weird, that partition manager cannot detect the drive, but there is "load" button in driver which will enable the drive for the whole system.

One of most ridiculous things I ever saw in windows.

Now everything is OK and works. Even after restart.

Comment: I presume the Windows 10 device driver considers the eSATA drive a "removable" drive, requiring a "mount", which you accidentally did with the "Load" in DeviceManager. (Right-click on the disk in Explorer and see if there is an 'Eject" option. If there is it is considered removable.) Windows 7 probably treated the drive as a non-removable internal SATA drive. I've seen some weird behavior related to this difference before.

Comment: I might have been misinformed with this eSATA information. I was googling it, and back then found out that L-shaped connector is eSata, now I found opposite info. So I don't know; the connector is L-shaped, this is all I know. I don't have access to that PC now, but I'll check "eject" option presence, and come back with info (if someone won't close this question). I don't recall, there was eject option. But even if there was, if the drive is online, plugged-in from OS start, it should be automounted, without having to search for load/mount button.

Comment: Shape of the connector doesn't mean much. eSata is a mess. Not well standardized and the actual connectors can vary. Some vendors call it eSata and it is just regular Sata with a connector on the outside of the case. Some Sata chipsets can be wired for eSata, but are not used as such. And some Sata chipsets can't be wired as such and are still used for eSata. Main thing is that Windows makes a subtle difference between removable and non-removable. If, after upgrade, the partiiontable/NTFS info doesn't match the removable status reported by the Sata drivers Windows can do weird things.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I'll try to find out more about the driver and update the question. However, to be honest, I consider this behavior as very suboptimal. Windows IS able to detect the drive, IS able to auto fix it, and just decided to not do anything. I mean at least there might have been information if I want to allow some fix. If windows can ask user about "shade of every pixel", question: "there seems to be problem with your HDD, would you like to fix it?" would be most welcomed. Thus I don't understand, why someone decided not to do so (if other OS does not have this issue)